# Chapter headers with extending vertical rulers

Tags: sectioning, chapters, koma-script

I'm trying to reproduce the example below on the right margin, but have come into serious errors.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,DIV=classic]{scrbook}
   \usepackage{scrpage2}
   \usepackage{lipsum}
   \usepackage{graphicx}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
{\normalfont\Large\raggedright}
{%
\llap{ \resizebox{!}{1.2cm}{\thechapter} \smash{\rule{.4pt}{10cm}} } }
{10pt}{\Huge}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A Chapter}

\end{document}
```

I tried adapting the code below, which works fine:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
 {\normalfont\Large\raggedleft}
 {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}%
 \rlap{ \resizebox{!}{1.2cm}{\thechapter} \smash{\rule{.4pt}{10cm}} } }
 {10pt}{\Huge}
```

But then I cannot get rid of `\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}` without messing things up.

What am I doing wrong here?

The result I expect is like:

[image]

Comment: Your first code doesn't produce any errors on my system (TeX Live2013) after loading `titlesec` in the preamble: `\usepackage{titlesec}`- What kind of errors do you get?

Comment: Both codes work fine, but what I want to do is mirror the first one (make it flush right). But when I try to do that with the `[hang]` option and as I said, taking out `\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}` (of the second code), it doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, now I see. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a possibility (adjust the lengths according to your needs):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,DIV=classic]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\normalfont\raggedleft}{}
  {10pt}
  {\Huge#1\rlap{%
    \hspace{1em}\smash{\rule[-2ex]{.4pt}{10cm}}~%
    \resizebox{!}{1.2cm}{\thechapter}}%
  }
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[hang]
  {\normalfont\raggedleft}{}
  {10pt}
  {\Huge#1\rlap{%
    \hspace{1em}\smash{\rule[-2ex]{.4pt}{10cm}}}%
  }

\begin{document}

\chapter{A numbered chapter}
\lipsum[4]
\chapter*{An unnumbered chapter}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

An image of a numbered chapter:

[image]

An image of an unnumbered chapter:

[image]

Comment: Nice, that's exactly what I had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Less code duplication than in Gonzalo's answer:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,DIV=classic]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newif\ifnumberedchapter

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\filleft}
  {\global\numberedchaptertrue}% this is executed only for numbered chapters
  {10pt}
  {\Huge\dochaptertitle}

\newcommand{\dochaptertitle}[1]{%
  #1% The title
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \hspace{1em}% one quad of space
    \smash{% this doesn't take vertical space
      \vrule height 10cm depth 2ex % the rule
      \ifnumberedchapter % the following will appear only for numbered chapters
        \enspace % some space
        \resizebox{!}{1.2cm}{\thechapter}%
      \fi
    }%
  }%
  \global\numberedchapterfalse
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A numbered chapter}
\lipsum[4]
\chapter*{An unnumbered chapter}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```